# .Net ObjectDataSource error: Object does not match target type

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, objectdatasource, 2-way-object-databinding

I have an ObjectDataSource on a page that is producing the error "Object does not match target type" when its Insert method is invoked. From Googling this message, I believe this the message is deceptive and I'm actually getting a null reference error on the object that the ObjectDataSource is trying to invoke the method on, but I'm darned if I can figure out why.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="dsAddComment" runat="server"  
     DataObjectTypeName="BookCatalogue.InteractionDocuments.UserComment"
     SelectMethod="GetNewComment" TypeName="BookCatalogue.AddCommentPresenter"
     InsertMethod="AddComment"  OnObjectCreating="dsAddComment_ObjectCreating" />
```

The Type that is being called upon Insert is an AddCommentPresenter. The method AddComment is not static. If I change this to static, I don't get the error and the method is found without problem. When it's not static, the error occurs. That's whyI htink that the underlying problem is that somehow I'm not getting a valid instance of my Presenter class when the AddComment method is invoked.

My AddCommentPresenter class doesn't have a parameterless constructor. This will cause an error normally. To get around it I'm overriding the ObjectCreating event in my page's code-behind and assigning an instance of the Presenter class.

`protected void dsAddComment_ObjectCreating(object sender, ObjectDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    e.ObjectInstance = presenter;
}`

I can step through my ObjectCreating method and it is a valid, non-null Presenter instance that's being passed into the e.ObjectInstance property.

My AddComment method has the correct signature.

```
    public void AddComment(UserComment newComment)
    {
        ...
    }
```

I've also checked the obvious things, like misspelling the type name on the aspx page, but all is correct there.

Anyone have any ideas? I must say that I find the ObjectDataSource class very difficult to work with....

Answer (score 3):

A colleague found the cause of my problem. The AddCommentPresenter class in my web app was defined in the website's App_Code directory. For some reason, that was causing the error. Move it out of there, into the main directory of the website and the code worked. I can't find any mention in any ObjectDataSource documentation of this being a potential gotcha for the control, but there you go.

I've also been told that it should be possible to keep the class in the App_Code folder, but include the syntax ",__code" at the end of the TypeName. E.g.

```
TypeName="MyNamespace.MyType,__code"
```

but personally, I didn't get that working when I tried it. Another post to an ASP.Net forum suggested changing the TypeName to

```
TypeName="_MyNamespace.MyType"
```

That didn't work for me, either. I ended up just pulling the class out of the App_Code folder.

Comment: Worked in my case too, man that was frustrating. In my case, this was a newly-created "Web Application" that had been converted from a "Web Site"....probably why these .cs files were in the `App_Code` directory in the first place. The debugger was anti-helpful because it wouldn't break anywhere, just dumped the exception to the browser! Oh, and it was only an issue in the VS development server ...worked fine when published to IIS! Hard to Google for, maybe this comment will help others find this.